# How to represent objects from multiple databases in the EF Mdel / Data Context class

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, dbcontext

I am working on an intranet app. My data context class has some references to table(s) in other databases.

For example, one of my classes is like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    ...
    public int EnteredById {get;set;}
}
```

Here is `EnteredById` is in fact a foreign key to `Employee` table in another database (on the same server) and that table is not part of the Data Context class.

I know I cannot create a foreign key on this property and this is fine as long as I can keep it in this class/ table and provide a value for it by going to Employee table in another database and retrieving it from there based on User’s Windows User Name.

How do I handle this situation while Employee table is not part of my Data Context?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific. The case you have described above has no real problems. Maybe you could be more specific in your naming that it's an external id. But since it's just a value in the database your program will have to deal with the verification that the data actually exists and what happens if that post disappears from the external database.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I hope this time I will be more specific. Let us assume that my controller needs to send a new object of type SomeClass to the view to be filled out by the user. User can enter all the information except one; that is EnteredById. For this he needs a drop-drown list of Employees to choose from. But my controller cannot retrieve a list of employees because it is in a different database and datacontext class doesn't have access to it. How do I handle this situation?